# The method '[]' was called on null. Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

**My futurebuilder is occure error above anyone have any solution The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder ..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
..........................**

```
noti.dart
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return FutureBuilder(
                future: postReference
                    .document(userId)
                    .collection("usersPosts")
                    .document(postId)
                    .get(),
                builder: (context, datasnapshot) {
                  if (!datasnapshot.hasData) {
                    return circularProgress();
                  }
                  Post post = Post.fromDocument(datasnapshot.data);
                  return Center(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: header(context, strTitle: post.description),
                      body: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: post,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });


    Post.dart

class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  final String ownerId;
  // final String timestamp;
  final dynamic likes;
  final String username;
  final String description;
  final String location;
  final String url;
  //
  Post({
    this.postId,
    this.ownerId,
    // this.timestamp,
    this.likes,
    this.username,
    this.description,
    this.location,
    this.url,
  });

  factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return Post(
      postId: documentSnapshot["postId"],
      ownerId: documentSnapshot["ownerId"],
      likes: documentSnapshot["likes"],
      // timestamp: documentSnapshot["timestamp"],
      username: documentSnapshot["username"],
      description: documentSnapshot["description"],
      location: documentSnapshot["location"],
      url: documentSnapshot["url"],
    );
  }
```

The  post method that refers to it:

```
displayPost(context) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => PostScreen(
        postId: postId,
        userId: userId,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Add the Post class

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you receive null values from your query.
You want to map documentSnapshot["postId"] to your Post and this event fails because of null.

For clean code I would suggest you to create a new Post model with [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/)
And map your Post with json.
Then check if value == null:

```
factory Score.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Score(
    score: json["score"] == null ? null : json["score"].toDouble(),
```